# no image, no text in App Bar for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm working on Windows Phone project, and troubles have found me as usual :) The application bar I'm trying to create doesn't show the specified image and text. When I do it on code it simply doesn't work as planned:

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        {
            ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();
            ApplicationBarIconButton specialAppBar = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
            specialAppBar.IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/special.png", UriKind.Relative);
            specialAppBar.Text = "special";
            ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(specialAppBar);
        }
```

And when I do it in XAML, it is displaying perfect at design time only:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/special.png" Text="special"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

I guess I'm missing smth important, but don't know what exactly. Will appreciate any help :) Thank you in advance

Comment: Code seems like it should work. What appears inside the button and is there no text underneath at all?

Comment: an image is set to this "cross"="X", and no text at all :\

Comment: Just to confirm, are you pressing the three dots at the end of the applicationbar? You can only see the text like that.

Comment: I'm hopeless idiot ^^ thank you, you're right, I was expecting it to appear from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Build Action property for "special.png" file. It should be "Content".

Comment: ^^ that is some kind of magic, thank you! But even when the image is okay, the text is still hidden...

Comment: If images aren't displayed it's for this reason in most cases :D